# How to use LoopBack in tcp connection

Tags: tcp

My application is very time critical. It communicates with another application thru TCP/IP. Both the applications are running on the same machine. My application is written in vb.net and of Course I have got the source. I communicate to that foreign application thru a socket. Whenever I send a message to that application it takes the normal time as it is running on some other computer on the same network. I want to reduce the time by bypassing the switch. Something like LOOPBACK. Can any one help

Answer (score 0):

If you use an address of 127.0.0.1 instead of the "normal" IP address of the machine, that should use the loopback adapter. I'd be surprised if it *really* took the same amount of time as a separate machine *at the network level* though - are you sure you're measuring network delivery time rather than (say) application response time?