# Hot to byepass lan switch

Tags: .net

My application is very time critical , It is written in .net 2.0 on windows server 2003 . It communicates with another application thru TCP/IP. Both the applications are running on the same machine. My application is written in vb.net and of Course I have got the source. I communicate to that foreign application thru a socket. I do not have the source of that foreign application. Whenever I send a message to that application it takes the normal time as it is running on some other computer on the same network. I want to reduce the time by bypassing the switch. Something like LOOPBACK. Can any one help? If I connect that application via my normal IP address i.e 191.191.191.11 and port 8585 it connects. But if in my application I use the address 127.0.0.1 port 8585 it refuses to connect and I receive an error message saying the machine you are trying to connect to has actively refused the connection. What to do....can anyone help?

Comment: You should accept answers on some of your previous questions- it will improve the likelihood that someone will answer this one.

Comment: You should also avoid asking the same question twice. Edit the original question to add more details (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768572/how-to-use-loopback-in-tcp-connection) if you are trying to draw more attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Even if you use the IP address 191.191.191.11, the packets probably don't go all the way to the switch. Your OS knows its own address.
- Whether you can connect on 127.0.0.1 port 8585 depends on whether the other application is *listening* on that port or not. An application can choose to bind to all addresses, or only some.